# use calendar as date picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, calendar

I'd like to popup a calendar control (like the month view from the calendar provided by Apple), which can be used as date picker. I've already made some research, but I'm asking if I missed something out.

There are several free available libraries:

  * Kal

  * GCCalendar

  * TapkuLibrary

  * iphonecal

  * iphone-gcal

Also there is one commercial library:

  * DTCalendarViewController

Also important is internationalization. Do you know another library which can offer that? Or how to adapt the free available libraries to use the calendar month view as a date picker?

Comment: You may need to clarify your question, are you looking for a Calendar that does internationalization well?

Comment: I only need internationalization for my country. Perhaps an English speaking country as well (US/UK).

Answer (score 1):

I have used the TapkuLibrary successfully for this. The only problem is that it only shows five weeks maximum per month so every now and then a month cannot be entirely shown. (For example last month (January 2011) and July 2011 coming up both needed to display 6 rows. You will have to modify the code to fix this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could show some code how you have done it or create a github repository for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer iOs library for this.in library already has sample code for it.
otherwise you can find code in google code.